# Can JAI.create() be used in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing, jai

I'm building a program based on the open source software JPiv, that is used to do digital image correlation and strain analysis. The algorithm in JPiv is, unfortunately, very slow, so I've been trying to use multithreading to decrease the time taken to analyse an image set. The algorithm uses JAI for something, not quite sure what as I've never used it before. When I run it, on the second 'pass', I get a OutOfMemory exception on at least one of the threads, and occasionally get other errors, seemingly at random, but usually IllegalArgument exceptions - sometimes from JAI, sometimes from standard Java libraries. The exceptions get thrown by different libraries at different points in the program, which makes it hard to debug - especially as they don't always give traceback messages in the console, for some reason.

I think the error is in the use of the JAI.create() method, and the way that the different threads access the corr[c] variable to use the above method. Is it possible to use JAI.create() in the way I'm trying to do so?

The code is quite lengthy, so I've put it on Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/EX92YjXA

Below is a bit of pseudo-code to get a general sense of what I'm attempting.

```
public doPivEvaluation{
corr = new BufferedImage
start threads
send corr array to threads
loop until threads have finished
do stuff with corr}

public class threads{
on start{
    do the analysis using tmpCorr
    pb = new ParameterBlock()

    pb.removeSources();
    pb.removeParameters();
    pb.addSource(PivEvaluation.corr[c]);
    pb.addSource(tmpCorr);
    PivEvaluation.corr[c] = JAI.create("add",pb,null).getAsBufferedImage();

end threads}
```

Uh, yeah, so maybe not the best pseudo-code ever, but yeah. The position in corr, c, is different for each thread (and refers to a set of pixels, so could be up to 5000 depending on the size of the image, split between the different threads), and corr has been declared volatile, so in theory there should be no overriding of data. Likewise, in theory, if JAI.create() only acts on that position, there should be no problem either. The problem arises because I don't understand how .create() actually works... I know the whole thing works in a single thread, because I've not changed anything of the actual algorithm, only moved it into multiple threads.

Also, apologies for any bad coding practices that may be in the code, I'm relatively new to Java still, so I'm more just muddling along. If I try something and it fixes a problem, I'm likely to go with it even it means multiple variable declarations or whatever other inefficiencies I've made. This is the first problem I've encountered I haven't been able to fix by guesswork and Google.